# What should I do when the bonsai server is down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, elasticsearch, tire

I am using ElasticSearch with Tire and host my app on Heroku.

Last night, when the bonsai server was down, my whole app crashed.
When I tried to deploy the app to Heroku, Tire tried to connect and create the index, and threw errors, so I had to move my `Tire` code from all models to an `unless` statement:

```
unless ENV['ES_DISABLED'] 
  # Elastic Search
  #
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  index_name INDEX_NAME

  tire.mapping do
    indexes :id, :type => 'string', :index => :not_analyzed
    indexes :content, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
  end
end
```

Of course I set the `ES_DISABLED` constant to `true` on Heroku.

I would like to be prepared for similar errors in the future. Is there a better way to avoid them?

Comment: i don't think that it is a tire default to create an index when deploying code or booting the app. are you sure that this isn't something you implented?

Comment: It happend during deploy to heroku. So maybe heroku trigger regenerate indexes.

Comment: @phoet Tire does indeed do it, but it tries to handle connection issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick with Bonsai.io here. My humble apologies for the outage that affected your app. You can find my [full post-mortem](http://go.bonsai.io/W3YXOz) on our blog.

Unless I am mistaken, I believe that Tire will attempt to create an index upon running the `tire.mapping` method call while Rails is evaluating and loading your model class.

It looks like this kind of scenario was partially addressed in [Issue #180](https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/180) and [commit (0df58dce)](https://github.com/karmi/tire/commit/0df58dce35335e4dae2ffb07a5e2cf9a3e99c863) for `ECONNREFUSED` issues, but that wouldn't cover a 503 error response from a node that is disconnected from the larger cluster, like our cluster experienced.

Perhaps this would make a good pull request for Tire to similarly rescue a 50x error when testing for the index presence or otherwise attempting to create the index and mapping?

Alternately, you might also be able to wrap the `tire.mapping` call in a `begin/rescue` on your end.

Comment: I don't see connection between the issue you link to and this error? In either case, the **application** code _should_ have a user-friendly way of handling the "Elasticsearch is down" situation.

Comment: Edit: So, the suggestion here is to bail out of any network-related errors?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, this is weird. Tire indeed tries to create an index for the model, when it doesn't exist, but it doesn't shoot the application down.

Notice I'm able to do this:

```
$ ps aux | grep java
121:karmi           7197   0.0  0.0  2432768    472 s003  R+    7:37PM   0:00.00 grep java

$ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
Article
Skipping index creation, cannot connect to Elasticsearch
(The original exception was: #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)>)
=> Article(id: integer, title: string, content: text, author: string, published_on: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
Article.search '*'
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
    from /Users/karmi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
  ...
    from /Users/karmi/Playground/ElasticSearch/Tire/tire/lib/tire/search.rb:35:in `results'
```

You **shouldn't** wrap your `mapping` etc definitions in begin/rescue -- instead, you should have a `rescue_from` or other means within the application code which will notify the user that the search feature is not working.

Comment: It doesn't seem like we can use rescue_from as Tire catches the Errno::ECONNREFUSED and returns `false`. Am I wrong?

Comment: It appears I am correct as far as the index creation is concerned but I can rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED elsewhere.

Comment: I think the question is more about 50x errors than ECONNREFUSED. For example, requests being directed to a node that has failed to join the rest of the cluster.

Comment: Nick is right, the current code only handles ECONNREFUSED, not HTTP errors returned by Elasticsearch. It's worth fixing; see https://github.com/karmi/tire/commit/0df58dce35335e4dae2ffb07a5e2cf9a3e99c863#L1R95